# Missing return in a function expected to return 'String' (answer not found)

Tags: swift

Here's the code

```
import Foundation
import ARKit

extension ARCamera.TrackingState {
    var presentationString: String {
        switch self {
        case .notAvailable:
            return "TRACKING UNAVAILABLE"
        case .normal:
            return "TRACKING NORMAL"
        case .limited(let reason):
            switch reason {
            case .excessiveMotion:
                return "TRACKING LIMITED\nToo much camera movement"
            case .insufficientFeatures:
                return "TRACKING LIMITED\nNot enough surface detail"
            case .initializing:
                return "INITIALIZING"
            case .relocalizing:
                return "RELOCALIZING"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on the second to last line saying:

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

If I add:

```
return "String"
```

I get an error saying:

> Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'" and "Expected declaration"

I've tried returning a string all over this code and nothing works.

Comment: Think about what happens when `self` is not one of the three values you've listed.

Comment: And show where you tried to add `return "String"`.

Comment: @rmaddy [Here's what I have right now](https://i.imgur.com/TK5UPkP.png)

Comment: @rmaddy [Here's what happens when I try to add default to the parent switch statement](https://imgur.com/a/GT0nD0n)

Comment: @rmaddy Welp, I deleted a bracket at the end of the code on accident, hit undo and the error went away. So then... I'm good to go with that first image.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't post details about your question in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `default` to each switch statement incase none of the other conditions are met.

```
switch self {
    case .notAvailable:
        return "TRACKING UNAVAILABLE"
    case .normal:
        return "TRACKING NORMAL"
    case .limited(let reason):
        // Do something
    default:
        // You can edit the string to return in this case (could be some error message)
        return ""
}
```

Comment: Putting "default: return ''" did the trick when inside of the second switch statement - that plus the error message just... going away when I didn't change anything solved the issue. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you out :)